# QT ntl выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, qt, библиотеки

Всех приветствую. Скачал файлы **ntl** библиотеки. Произвел сборку (через **INCLUDEPATH**  подключил папку заголовочников). 
К новому проекту добавляю:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ntl-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/release/ -lntl
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ntl-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/ -lntl
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-ntl-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/ -lntl
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../ntl/WinNTL-9_6_2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../ntl/WinNTL-9_6_2/include
```

Внутри `main` подключаю `< NTL/ZZ.h >`

В итоге, на строчку `"ZZ b;"` **Qt** выдает следующее:

```
C:\Users\psy_duck\Documents\build-tik-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN3NTL2ZZ7Deleter5applyERPl':
C:\Users\psy_duck\Documents\ntl\WinNTL-9_6_2\include\NTL\ZZ.h:39: ошибка: undefined reference to `_ntl_zfree(long**)'
```

Что с этим делать, кто-нибудь знает?

Answer (score 1):

Порядок действий:

1. Собираем библиотеку.
2. Полученный файл с расширением ***lib** запихиваем в папку проекта.
3. Подключаем либу в файлы проекта.
4. Если что не работает - копируем папку `NTL` из папки `include` (скачанные исходники библиотеки) и саму полученную либу, и добавляем в файлы студии (`Programm Files/Visual Studio 9.0` и т.д)